# Lost old home directory while switching linux distro

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I had garuda linux installed since I was facing lot of stability issues with it. I decided to go with linux mint cinnamon edition. While installation I chose manual partitioning. Following are the changes I made while installation

1. For root partitioon, I ticked on format partition and selected mount point as root and file system as btrfs earlier also it was btrfs.
2. I did not select format partition for my old home partition and selected mount point as home with btrfs
3. Eventualy I selected my efi partition for bootloader installtion
4. After going through selecting timezone and maybe installation screen I was asked what to name the user directory. I switched OS after a long time so I forgot that to reuse the same old home directory we have to name it same while switching a distro and I renamed it with something else.
   After I booted, I saw that my old home data was not there and realized that I made a mistake while naming.

Now, If I check through gparted it shows me that out of 142 Gb of home partition 75 GB is already used. Out of which 72 GB is probably of old user directory and 3 GB is from new user directory I have.
I tried to look at hidden files in my home directory and it doesn't show old user directory there.
I also tried testdisk but it also doesn't show old user directory in it's analysis so I am assuming it's not deleted and it's there but I don't know how can I access it since I can't see it anywhere.

Your help is greatly appreciated if I can somehow access my old user directory

Comment: Is there a way to migrate the question to those forums ?

Comment: Yes, I'll flag it. Hold on. I asked a moderator to migrate to Unix&LInux.

Comment: yeah @DavidC.Rankin, but the old username home directory is nowhere to be seen to be accessible

Comment: If you `ls -al /home` and can't see the old user directory. Try again as root. The new distribution may use a differed GID for a common group that provides read-access to the old user directory. The key right now is to mount `/home` as READ ONLY to avoid the possibility of further compromise of the data. `mount -o remount,ro /home` (you can't have open files on `/home` when you remount) You may need to shutdown and boot from the install disk and `chroot` the new system or just mount the old `/home` at a temporary mount point under `/mnt` directly from the installer.

Comment: I tried ```ls -al /home``` as root and I only get current user directory and not the old one. Regarding mounting home as read only, I am not sure how to do that. Would it be okay to follow [this](https://linuxconfig.org/howto-mount-usb-drive-in-linux) guide

Comment: Hi, I don't know the terminal way to above things so in live usb I simply went to file manager mounted my /home partition and checked it's content. I could find @home folder which contains current user directory inside it. I also found a guest folder and old user directory folder with my contents in it.

Comment: Ouch. The command line is where you will need to be. In your live USB, just open up a terminal (an xterm or gnome-terminal or konsole in KDE). You can look at your partitions with `cat /proc/partitions` You can identify the partitions by size. The device for that partitions is listed on the right size. (e.g. `sda1` is `/dev/sda1`) which you can use to mount a partition if unmounted (e.g. `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`). You check if a partition is mounted by simply typing `mount` (or `cat /proc/mounts` - same thing). I'm thinking your old partition may be a separate unmounted partition.

Comment: You can see which physical partition goes with which device by `ls -al /dev/disk/by-id`.

Comment: According to my understanding, there is no separate partition that has been created what happened is linux mint created a ```@home``` folder inside home partition which contains current linux mint user directory. So my previous distro user directory is intact and is still in current user directory. Attaching the results - 
Did this ```mount /dev/nvme0n1p6 /mnt``` followed by ```ls /mnt``` which gave ```@home guest surajm``` and surajm is my old home user directory and contains the data I need. I found same results by simply mounting through file manager on live usb

Comment: Awesome. Glad your found you data. That's nuts for mint to create `@home` in addition to the existing `home`. Sounds like nothing was lost or damaged. You may want to take a few minutes and write up an answer to your own question here. Drop a comment if you do, I'm happy to drop back by and vote for a well-explained and formatted answer.

Comment: Correction in my last comment: So my previous distro user directory is intact and is still in existing home partition

Comment: Nothing stopping you creating a new user account that matches the one you used you have

Comment: I tried that @roaima, I have also posted the results in my answer

Answer (score 1):

## I will start with listing down things that I tried to access my lost old home directory:

- Did `ls -al /home` with and without root still couldn't find any user directory other than the one created by new installation
- I tried `testdisk` and couldn't find any trace of deleted content that was matching my old user directory this kinda made me sure that atleast the data is not deleted and is just hidden in some way or other
- I also tried `find [path] -name [filename from old user directory]` as root but couldn't find any result out of it as well
- Installed `ncdu`  and ran it for /home and I could see space usage only for newly installed current user directory
- I booted using live usb and tried this `cat /proc/partitions` and identified my home partition from results. I mounted my home partition through `mount [partition_name] /mnt` and then I did `ls -al /mnt` which gave `@home guest [old_user_directory]`. I checked contents inside `[old_user_directory]` and that is it. I could access my old home partition's user directory data. I copied it for backup and then tried few more things.
- Finally, I tried changing owner and group permission for [old_user_directory] and then booted into my current installation and still I could not find any trace of my old user directory there.

### Some Observations:

- `@home` directory contained user directory of currently installed
  linux mint
- I tried reinstalling linux mint but this time I gave user directory name as [old_user_directory_name] and I noticed that this user directory was again created within `@home` inside my home partition when looked through live usb mount.
- Seems like user directories created by mint are residing inside `@home` and user directories from my previous distro remain inside home partition but outside `@home`